# access to a server apache that has virtualhost

Tags: apache, lampp

I have a cloud server with lampp installed on. I had configured a virtual host here like that:

```
<VirtualHost xx.xxx.xx.xxx:80>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/folder/"
    ServerName www.xxx.com
</VirtualHost>
```

and everything work as i expect, if i go to www.xxx.com i see my 'folder' site.
Now i need to work to another site present on the same server, but it doesn't allready have a domain, so i had imagine (by reading the apache's configuration file explanation)that i have to do it in this way:

```
<VirtualHost xx.xxx.xx.xxx:80>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/folder/"
    ServerName www.xxx.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost xx.xxx.xx.xxx:80/test>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/test/"
</VirtualHost>
```

But it doesn't work, if i do http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:80 i reach the 'folder' site while if i do http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:80/test rather the reach the 'test' site i still reach www.xxx.com, why? How could i reach this objective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The virtual host defined first (top most) acts as default host. That one is used to respond to any incoming requests that are *not* matched by a specific host name in the request.

You want to try this setup:

```
# some fallback host for testing and development
<VirtualHost xx.xxx.xx.xxx:80>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/_default"
</VirtualHost>
# a virtual host with a specific host name
<VirtualHost xx.xxx.xx.xxx:80>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/example.com"
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

*(here `xx.xxx.xx.xxx` stands for the systems public and routable IPV4 address)*

In your file system you have this hierarchy:

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs/
                  _default/
                           test1/
                           test2/
                  example.com/
```

This way requests to `http://example.com` or `http://www.example.com` are mapped to the folder `/opt/lampp/htdocs/example.com`, requests to URLs with *any other* host name to the default folder `/opt/lampp/htdocs/_default` in which you now can create as many sub folders as you like for different applications.

Another approach would be to use other host names below your existing domain name for internal tests, so something like `test1.example.com` or similar. That way you do not have to use raw IP addresses with their routing risk.